# Slice of one dataframe into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 consisting of a single column with zeros and another dataframe df2 of similar length, but containing a single column of spectral data, i.e. peaks.

Given that I've found the peak locations in df2, I would like to take a slice of df2 centered on each of the peaks and insert the corresponding values in df1, thereby replacing the zeros.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy
# load spectrum
df2 = numpy.array([1,2,5,3,1,0.5,0.4,1,2,5,3,0.1,0.3,0.6,1,2,5,1.5,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.9,1,3,5,2.5],dtype = float)
# generate zero array equivalent to spectrum
df1 = numpy.zeros(len(df2),dtype = float)

# you know what is the peak value
peakvalue = 5
selectedpoints = []
# identify the peak point places
for i in range(len(df2)): 
    if df2[i] == peakvalue:
        selectedpoints.append(i)

# how much len to select on each side
selected_len = 1
for i in range(len(selectedpoints)):
    df1[selectedpoints[i]-selected_len : selectedpoints[i]+selected_len+1] = df2[selectedpoints[i]-selected_len : selectedpoints[i]+selected_len+1]

print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found a solution to the problem soon after posting my question:

```
df1["counts"][(peak.index[0]-win_size):(peak.index[0]+win_size)] = df2[(peak.index[0]-win_size):(peak.index[0]+win_size)]
```

where df1 was the dataframe consisting of zeros (with column "counts") and peak is a dataframe containing the peak locations originating from df2